# Loading JS on demand

Tags: javascript

I am having lots of javascript. I want to load the js whenever it's needed.

For e.g . I am having textbox and button.Validating textbox is in jsfile_1.js, I want to load the js file on click of button. I don't want to load on pageload.

If i am using 10 js files on the page. On page load one file has to get loaded,remaining has to get load on demand. Please let  me know the most precise way to achive this. I tried with requireJS, But i can see all files get load on page load itself.

Comment: Require.JS is a library that lets you do the same. http://requirejs.org

Comment: @Runner Read the last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up "ajxjs" in this documentation:

http://www.antradar.com/docs-nano-ajax-manual

Or using plain JavaScript, you can just dynamically create a script element:

```
var rq=document.createElement('script');
rq.setAttribute('src','myjavascript.js');
document.body.appendChild(rq);
```